# How to configure Liferay login portlet to function as a CAS gateway

Tags: java, liferay, portal, cas

We've configured Liferay to use CAS. However, it only works when you click the sign in link in the top right. The standard login portlet where you enter your username/password does not go against CAS. We would like to have this portlet use CAS, which I'm assuming would be via the proxy method.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I figured this would be an out-of-the-box sort of functionality once you enable CAS within Liferay, but it appears to not be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the main advantages for using any SSO solution (like CAS) is that the single applications don't ever get access to your password - it's solely in the realm of the SSO solution to handle this.

My advice is to remove the standard login portlet from the page instead of changing it to go to CAS. You can add a link to the CAS login page if you want, but you don't need the login portlet for that.

Comment: This is fine as long as you do not need the "Create Account" functionality which is provided by the login portlet.My use case is to let new users register with Liferay, LR then exports the data to LDAP, and then the next login would happen via CAS which talks to the same LDAP. If I hide or delete the login portlet, then I do not know how to access the "Create Account" functionality.

Comment: Correct, but I assume that whenever you're using SSO you most likely have other means to store the user accounts and passwords, so you won't use Liferay's built-in self-registration. Of course that's not  100% true, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I agree that in many cases user account management is done outside Liferay. However, we'd like to use Liferay's self-registration facility. I would be really grateful if you could explain how to present _only_ the Create Account link from the Login portlet; I asked this question [in the Liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17716916) and on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237244/liferay-login-via-cas-create-account-functionality-via-login-portlet) but got no replies yet. Thx!

Comment: Figured out a hack that hides the username/password fields and the Login button, see [answer to my own question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237244/liferay-login-via-cas-create-account-functionality-via-login-portlet) :-)

Comment: Hello user465139 , so far I too solved with this very similar solution. Anyway the 'forgot password' and the click on reset password from email is going to authenticate automaticcally bypassing CAS , that's even worse. Did you found the same problem ?